# What language is used for text with dynamic text {name}

Tags: php, javascript

What language is used for dynamic text in my system
Sample

```
<html>
<title>{name title}</title>
{css load}
{script load}
<body>
<div>
{headers}
</div>
```

how do I do that?
php with javascript ?

Comment: try Antlr -> http://code.google.com/p/antlrphpruntime/

Comment: looks like handlebars. http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be using a [templating engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29). There are many available for both PHP and Javascript. I'd suggest having a Google around and deciding on which one best suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<?php
echo '<script src='.$src.'> </script> ';
echo '<link href='.$src.' /> ';

?>
<body>
<div>
<?php echo $header; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this is THE WORST possible solution! you should never ever mix html and php this way on any production website

Answer (score 0):

This looks somewhat like smarty(dot net) but you can easily create a very basic template engine yourself.

first create a template

```
//........
<div align="right"> 
    $name
</div>
//........ and the like
```

then add the variables you need

```
$name = "TuyoshiiBrasil";
```

and at the end of your php...

```
//fetch template und output
$template = addslashes(implode('', file("std.tpl"))); //where std.tpl is the template above
eval ("\$output = \"$template\";");
echo stripslashes($output);
```

It's not nearly as powerfull as the template engines you'll find on the net, and as you recognize it uses a different syntax too,
but it's very easy to implement, since you only need THREE lines of code